# Creating a keyword based search in python

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have a giant CSV file with close to 6K entries and the file looks something like this:

```
PDB ID  NDB ID  Structure Title  Citation Title     Abstract
1ET4    1ET4    Structure of     Solution structure Research was performed and 
                haemoglobin mRNA of mRNA aptamer    structure of mRNa was obtained
                aptamer.
```

My end goal is to display an output given a keyword like so:

```
Keyword: mRNA
PDB ID   NDB ID   Structure Title   Citation Title   Abstract   Location of first hit
                                                                struc/citation/abstract
```

What would be a starting point for me? Also, do I have to use something called Regex for this?

Disclaimer: This is part of a research project, not school homework.

A pseudocode or template would be great for me.

Comment: Prehaps have a look at: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Whoosh/

Comment: @JonClements: I think Whoosh and dictionary creation might help me a lot.

Comment: This is a slightly annoying file format, if your example is correct. Do you really have the data split across lines that way? If so, you're going to have to work a little to get that data into a useable form. That's assuming you care about having the title and abstract - if you just want keywords, it's a little easier.

Comment: @JonKiparsky: Yes unfortunately, the file is structured that way and I need the output as I described. I am planning to create dictionaries for the three columns that contain the text and then use Whoosh to look for the records containing the keywords.

Comment: @JonKiparsky: What would be a "useable" format? Text perhaps?

Comment: I would prefer a format that kept fields coherent, rather than splitting them up across lines. So, fields separated by a separator - not necessarily a comma, but you know, CSV. It's not so bad, though. If you have a way to determine where the columns are, this is tolerable, though you have to do a bit of extra work to reassemble the fields that you're split across lines.

Comment: Your job will be much easier if you can generate this data as CSV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could parse the CSV file and create two data structures. Both dictionaries.

One dictionary would contain each line, keyed on `PDB ID`. The other dictionary would store sets of `PDB ID`s and be keyed on keywords.

Below is just example code because I'm ignoring headers. You probably want to parse the csv properly...

```
from collections import defaultdict
entries = {}
keywords = defaultdict(set)

with open('my_csv.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        entries[line.split()[0]] = line  # so keying on the PDB ID

with open('my_csv.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        for kw in line.split()[1:]
            keywords[kw].add(line.split()[0])
```

Once you have those two data structures it should be trivial to look up a keyword in the keywords dict, iterate over the set, and print out each line with the relevant PDB id.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to look at regular expressions. Try the following library http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html
that you can also find by typing "csv python" on google.

There are many examples in there.